# Acceder a una función en otro archivo mediante jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Quiero trabajar con un calendario en el que seleccionar fechas y encontré que `jQuery UI` me ofrece una [solución](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range).

La cosa está en que este calendario me gustaría que apareciera en diferentes puntos de la web y por lo tanto, a mi parecer, lo suyo sería guardarlo en un fichero propio `.js` e ir llamándolo en los puntos que me haga falta para así no tener tanto código repetido.

Buscando por internet vi que la solución era emplear el código siguiente, pero no me funciona. (Lo puse que se muestre al pulsar un botón).

```
$('.btn_graf').click(function() {
    $.getScript("datepicker_range.js", function(){
        alert("Archivo cargado!");
    });
    //console.log("Los valores del calendario son:");
});
```

Mi duda viene, a si estoy empleando un método incorrecto o si es que estoy escribiéndolo mal. Además de que esta manera, no me retorna los valores de las fechas seleccionadas por el usuario pero eso imagino que en algún sitio me faltará igualarlo a una variable para obtenerlo.

A continuación muestro el código del selector de calendario que tengo un archivo llamado `datepicker_range.js`,

```
$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $( "#from" )
    .datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
    }),
    to = $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
    });

    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }

      return date;
    }
  } )
```

Comment: Mira en la consola del navegador a ver qué fallo o mensaje de error aparece. Sin saber más, intuyo que la URL del script a cargar no es correcta y por tanto no te está cargando el fichero

Comment: Exacto, yo también pienso que el problema está en que la URL del script no es correcta...